# What is the term for a pop-up box that fades away but remains accessible at all times?

Tags: popup

[Workday](http://www.workday.com/) seems to have implemented a really slick feature. A pop-up box appears that has the following features

a) It fades away when not in focus but not quite fully. Transparent I would say
b) It can be dragged around
c) User can work on other items
d) Support for a close, gear, hyperlinks within box

What is the term that describes this pop-up?

Comment: NotePad++ does that also; I hate it; it makes things harder to see and use.

Comment: If this feature is implemented in a web application, try to locate it in the code (with Firebug for example). Maybe you can find a name or a framework there. Other than that, jQuery UI supports dragable pop-ups and I think transparency is also supported... But I never really worked with it.

Comment: @Max - I think I have seen this in Notepad++. Its much slicker than that. It pretty much fully disappears with a very light shade remaining when not the window in focus.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or some such? I have visited the site but can't find what you are talking about?

Comment: @Marjan - looks like I already submitted the action in Workday and now cannot go back to that screen. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the scenario.

- If you're referring to the pop-up you get when you click the "Related Actions" button, I would call this a "tear-off" (click the button, and then drag the handle at the top of the popup window; you "tore it off" from where it was originally anchored to)
- If it's in the context of being able to see more specific information about  an otherwise general topic, I believe the correct Workday term for this is "drill-down".

Neither of these terms really has a requirement to be semi-transparent, although "overlay" comes to mind in this case. I personally have not encountered a feature like the one you have described. Of course, Workday is changing things every other day, so it will probably show up sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the term that describes this pop-up?

I dont think there exists a term for this but at best I would describe it as "Windows that enables transparency when out of focus" Netbeans IDE also refers to it as this way and so does notepad++

> Which javascript frameworks support this feature?

For the transparancey? I would say the simple old [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). For the window elements/gui features (dragging, support for gear, close etc), [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) There are many plugins that are built upon the jQUery UI to provide a more rich gui experiance

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: Well you need to give an image of the box u have in mind. Slick is a very broad word u need to be precise if you want us to understand what ur imagining. Maybe a rough sketch in pain or w.e? Idk but something

Comment: agreed! unfortunately I was not able to redo that piece in Workday to be able to provide that.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the term that describes this pop-up?

The term is **dialog**. You can optionally make dialogs modal, draggable, and transparent.  You can put different buttons on them for different actions. And much more.

As has been mentioned, jQuery UI does this quite well. I've used it *many* times.

Here are some live examples:

- https://jqueryui.com/dialog/
- http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/uidialog/
- http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/05/jquery-ui-dialog-examples.html

Comment: No, none of the examples illustrate the behavior I observed. Again, as I said it was very slick. It was barely visible. The closest I english word I can come up with is "hint". It was a barely visible hint if I needed to get quick access to functionality while I proceeded with my main task.